# Is there a way to move from one firebase collection to another collection including its document in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im working on e-commerce project, im trying to move data in `'cart'` collection into `'orders'` collection once the user complete with payment so that i can create order history. previously i have no problem moving single data in firestore but since orders can have multiple item, how do i move it all to another collection?

here is the way i found but its not working.

```
CollectionReference copyFrom = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).collection('cart');
CollectionReference copyTo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).collection('orders');

      copyFrom.get().then((value) => {
         copyTo.add(value)
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no move operation in the Firestore API, so you'll have to read each document, then write it to its new location, and delete it from its original location. You might want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
cartToCompletedOrders() async {
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
var currentUser = auth.currentUser;
QuerySnapshot qn = await _firestoreInstance
    .collection("users-cart-items")
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
    .collection("items")
    .get();
setState(() {
  for (int i = 0; i < qn.docs.length; i++) {
    CollectionReference collectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("completed-orders");
    collectionRef.doc(currentUser!.email).collection("items").doc().set({
      "name": qn.docs[i]["name"],
      "price": qn.docs[i]["price"],
    }).then((value) => print("Added to completed-orders"));
  }
});}
```